# Which is faster retrieving data from internet or from database in android app?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, retrofit2

I am creating a quiz app which is for now retrieving list of data objects from retrofit and as data is asynchronous , it takes 2 or 3 seconds to retrieve it.

But there are apps which are using databases instead of retrieving whole sum of data from internet. As i have never worked with android sq-lite which is better for performance and will produce efficient results?

What are your opinion do i have to change my app and work with sq-lite instead of retrofit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting value from local database is faster.
But when working online you have other benifits.
You have to figure out what fits you better.

Answer (score 0):

To getting faster data you can use retrofit REST API for live storage and Room Database for local storage instand of using SQLite Database.